# Update Column using Rownum

Tags: oracle11g, rownum

I am trying to update a column based on the rownumber. Table Unpaid1  contain multiple transactions for alot of accounts. When i execute the following script, I often end up transactions With incorrect sequential number (Cycleage) like shown below. The cycleage should be in the order 1 to 4 from oldest to newest. What might be the cause of this issue? Is there another way to assign the cycleage?

```
Begin 
For X in (Select * From temp_Unpaid1 order by trxnserno asc) 
  loop 
  Update temp_Unpaid1 t set t.cycleage = rownum where t.custid=x.custid; 
  end loop; 
End; 


+-----------+-----------+--------+--------+----------+
| TRXNSERNO | CUSTID    | AMOUNT |  DATE  | CYCLEAGE |
+-----------+-----------+--------+--------+----------+
|        66 |        45 |    -10 | 08.jan |        2 |
|        67 |        45 |    -20 | 10.jan |        1 |
|        90 |        45 |    -30 | 15.jan |        3 |
|       155 |        45 |    -15 | 20.jan |        4 |
+-----------+-----------+--------+--------+----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

The catch is that the ROWNUM in the update is *independent* of the SELECT statement and, in fact, it looks like you are doing unnecessary updates. Here's why:

The SELECT will return all rows in the order of TRXNSERNO and even if you have only the one custid, you'll get 4 rows with the same custid:

```
CUSTID  TRXNSERNO ...(other columns)
45      66
45      67
45      90
45      155
```

Then *for each* of these rows, the update statement will run (so you'll be updating the same 4 rows 4 times.)

When the UPDATE runs, it finds the 4 rows for custid 45 (it doesn't know/care what the TRXNSERNO was in the SELECT) and updates them in whatever order it finds them. (There's nothing in the UPDATE statement that forces the order of the rows as they are updated.)

So, whatever order the (4th and last) update found them in is how the ROWNUM values will be assigned so if Oracle found them in the order of

```
CUSTID  TRXNSERNO
45      67
45      66
45      90
45      155
```

Then the ROWNUM value will be in that order:

```
CUSTID  TRXNSERNO ROWNUM
45      67        1
45      66        2
45      90        3
45      155       4
```

In another run (depending on circumstances) Oracle might execute the update and find the custid 45 rows in a completely different order like the following and assign them rownums accordingly:

```
CUSTID  TRXNSERNO ROWNUM
45      155       1
45      66        2
45      90        3
45      67        4
```

You could keep your current code but just generate the ROWNUMs in the SELECT list and apply the value in the update to the custid/trxnserno pairs:

```
Begin 
For X in 
   (Select tmp.*
         , row_number() over (partition by tmp.custid order by tmp.trxnserno) as rn 
      From temp_Unpaid1 tmp) 
  loop 
     Update temp_Unpaid1 t 
        set t.cycleage = rn 
      where t.custid=x.custid
        and t.trxnserno = x.trxnserno; 
  end loop; 
End;
```

Alternatively, you could try this in a single SQL statement using something like MERGE and using only the WHEN MATCHED portion of it:

```
MERGE INTO temp_unpaid1 temp
USING
(Select t.*
         , row_number() over (partition by custid order by trxnserno) as rn 
      From temp_Unpaid1
) rn_qry
ON (temp.custid = rn_qry.custid 
    AND temp.trxnserno = rn_qry.trxnserno
   )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
   UPDATE SET
      temp.cyclage = rn_qry.rn
;
```

Note: unfortunately I can't test the accuracy of the syntax right now, but hopefully this is of some value. :)